# Experience of vs Experience with

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

What is the difference between the two, and which one of the following is correct?
1) Your country's experience of democracy.
2) Your country's experience with democracy.

Comment: They're very similar aren't they?
To me the first sounds as if the country has been a democracy. The second could be asked of a country which hasn't, though it may have had brief spells of democracy, or it may have had dealings with democratic countries, or it may have suppressed internal pro-democracy movements.


The first sounds more idiomatic to me: more natural than the second, which sounds very slightly 'pointed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both prepositions, **of** and **with** work after **experience** but the choice is likely to depend on the context. For example, it is more natural to say:

> I don't have much experience of mountain climbing

indicating that the speaker is relatively new to mountain climbing and implying that s/he would not wish to tackle difficult climbs. On the other hand, you might say:

> I don't have much experience with John at the helm
>   or
>   I don't have much experience with this particular model

indicating that your limited experience is not **of** John, but **with** his leadership  - and with driving a particular vehicle.

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **of** is about three times as popular as **with** in this context.

In some examples, including those you give, both prepositions are idiomatic and the meaning is the same.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=experience+of%2Cexperience+with&year